# Unit Test in Spring Boot for multiple values of property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I'm having a Spring Boot application that defines a property `application.mode` inside my property file. The value of this property can be either `SINGLE` or `MULTI`.

`src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
application.mode=SINGLE

# also possible
#application.mode=MULTI
```

Some beans and bonfigs are loaded depending on the value of this property.

`src/main/java/com.example.SomeService.java`

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${application.mode}'.equalsIgnoreCase(\"SINGLE\")")
public class SomeService {
   // some code
}
```

I also have a `@SpringBootTest` to check if the context loads and all beans are configured correctly.

`src/test/java/com.example.SpringBootApplicationTest.java`

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringBootApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

Currently I copied the `application.properties` file to `src/test/resources` folder. I manually start the unit test twice and edit the `application.mode` value in between to check if the Spring context loads with both values.

Is there a way to run this unit-test twice automatically and inject a different `application.mode` value for each run?

Comment: Why `@ConditionalOnExpression` and not simply `@ConditionalOnProperty`.  You can use `@TestPropertySource` on your test to specify the property value.

Comment: @M.Deinum That's a good point. I already have replacing the annotation on my TODO list (I inherited the code and want to refactor it). Using `@TestPropertySource` sounds like a great idea. I will give it a look. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override certain properties (even without properties file in `src/test/resources`) like so:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "application.mode=SINGLE" })
class Whatevertest {
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure that you can test both cases in 1 test class, but creating 2 test classes should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I wrote multiple test classes and injected the property values like that.